# Toughest self-tap screwable glue?

Tags: screws, adhesive, threading

I have a self-tapping screw that has stripped through its plastic (I can't be more specific) housing. What's the toughest (as in resistant to stripping, it's not particularly load bearing) glue that I can fill it with, and still be able to drive it in once set? (I do need to be able to remove it again.)

For example, a two-part epoxy would be nice and strong, but it wouldn't tap. A 'hot melt' stick would be easy, but I'm not convinced it would hold well; likewise a silicone sealant or caulking. A PVA wood glue should be possible to screw into, but I think it might just start to crumble rather than hold a thread? Perhaps 'Gorilla Glue'?

Comment: A good way to be "more specific" is to post a picture.  If we can see the screw and the hole it came out of this will help us understand the situation.

Comment: It might help to include a picture of the part with the stripped hole, as well as indicating the _type_ of plastic. Different plastics can require different techniques.

Comment: @tnknepp jinx! :)

Comment: Use a an epoxy compatible with the plastic, then once it's set drill a hole slightly smaller than the shaft of the screw.

Answer (score 1):

I would drill out the plastic and glue in a plastic rod of a suitable diameter then re-drill the hole as necessary.

This does of course depend on the thickness of the material that is being worked with.

Another option is to glue a fresh piece of plastic behind to give more support to the screw.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's very small, and no (convenient) access behind. I jumped to glue thinking that would be an easy way of filling it with plastic, just formed in situ.

Comment: To be honest if I had room to do this without splitting the plastic that remains I'd just set a nut or threaded insert in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the two part epoxy and drill a pilot hole for the self-tapper to get started in. Take care to only drill through the material, as there may be something beneath that doesn't like being drilled at the same time.